# How to test dependency injection with PHPUnit on symfony 4

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, phpunit, traits

In a symfony 4 project, many services/controllers need log.
Trying to use the advantage of traits & autowire options given by symfony, I created a loggerTrait that will be passed to the different services.

```php
namespace App\Helper;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LogLevel;

trait LoggerTrait
{
    /** @var LoggerInterface */
    private $logger;

    /** @var array */
    private $context = [];

    /**
     * @return LoggerInterface
     */
    public function getLogger(): LoggerInterface
    {
        return $this->logger;
    }

    /**
     * @required
     *
     * @param LoggerInterface|null $logger
     */
    public function setLogger(?LoggerInterface $logger): void
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function logDebug(string $message, array $context = []): void
    {
        $this->log(LogLevel::DEBUG, $message, $context);
    }
...
}
```

(inspired by [symfonycasts.com](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-fundamentals/logger-trait))

A service will be using this trait

```php
namespace App\Service;

use App\Helper\LoggerTrait;

class BaseService
{
    use LoggerTrait;

    /** @var string */
    private $name;

    public function __construct(string $serviceName)
    {
        $this->name = $serviceName;
    }

    public function logName()
    {
        $this->logInfo('Name of the service', ['name' => $this->name]);
    }
}
```

It works perfectly but I couldn't succeed to test it.

I tried to extend KernelTestCase in my test to mock an loggerInterface but I receive **Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: The "Psr\Log\LoggerInterface" service is private, you cannot replace it** which make perfect sens.

Here my test:

```php
namespace App\Tests\Service;

use App\Service\BaseService;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;

class BaseServiceTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    private function loggerMock()
    {
        return $this->createMock(LoggerInterface::class);
    }

    protected function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();
    }

    /**
     * @test
     * @covers ::logName
     */
    public function itShouldLogName()
    {
        // returns the real and unchanged service container
        $container = self::$kernel->getContainer();

        // gets the special container that allows fetching private services
        $container = self::$container;

        $loggerMock = $this->loggerMock();
        $loggerMock->expect(self::once())
            ->method('log')
            ->with('info', 'Name of the service', ['name' => 'service_test']);

        $this->logger = $container->set(LoggerInterface::class, $loggerMock);


        $baseService = new BaseService('service_test');
        var_dump($baseService->getLogger());
    }
}
```

Is there a solution to test such a logger inside the service ?

Comment: $baseService->setLogger($loggerMock) should do the trick.  No need to fool around with the container or to test the @required functionality.

Comment: Is it okay to use it in the test even if do not use it in the service ?

Comment: setLogger is used in the service.  It is just automatically called for you (thanks to @required) by the container.  As a general rule, avoid the container for regular unit tests.

Comment: ok, thank you for confirming this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the service to be `public` (only for the `test` environment)  in your `config_test.yml` as follows:

```
services:
  Psr\Log\LoggerInterface:
    public: true
```

This is commonly done for testing private services.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not change the service.. I still have "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: The "Psr\Log\LoggerInterface" service is private, you cannot replace it." error.